# How to make a perspective transform?

Tags: modeling, mesh

When I import  a model for 3D printing, I find that I prefer the mesh in  perspective view to the mesh  in orthogonal view. 
How can I transform the mesh  to perspective effect in the orthogonal view?
[image]

Comment: I am unclear of what your goal is. Do you want to warp your mesh, so it gets a "fisheye effect" when looking at it from the front?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want. Is there any good way? Thanks

Comment: To do it exactly like perspective distortion you'd have to do a lot of math.
The easiest way to fake it would be a cast modifier.
I toyed around with proportional vertex editing, that seems to give me reasonable results.